# Potassium permanganate structurre

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, lewis-structure

So I'm learning about Lewis structures for university. I was reading a book written by some teachers from my university and in one exercise they ask us to draw the Lewis structure for potassium permanganate ($KMnO4$). I attempted to do it, but when I compared my answer to that of the book I realized what I did was wrong.

[image: Structure found on my book]

This is the book's structure. However, when calculating the formal charge of the central manganese atom, I got $7-6-0 = 1$, and as far I understand, the best structure has a negative charge on one of the oxygen atoms, since they are more electronegative

So I looked up the structure online and I found that both my structure and that of the book were wrong.

[image: Most common structure online]

This is the most common structure I found. Here, the formal charge for Mn is $7-7-0=0$, for the upper oxygen atom $6-1-6=-1$ and for the other oxygen atoms $6-2-4=0$, which makes more sense according to what I wrote before about oxygen being more electronegative than manganese.

[image: Wikipedia's structure]

However, I also found this another possible structure, this time on Wikipedia, where the formal charge of the central Mn atom is $7-8-0=-1$, and that of the oxygen atoms is $6-2-4=0$. So according to what I mentioned before regarding the formal charge, this structure is wrong as well.

I think the only right structure is the second one. Am I right?

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: I won't go so far as to say the second is right, but I would say it is the least incorrect of the 3 you show :) If you said that it was number 2 but that a better picture had all 4 Oxygens equivalent with a formal charge of -0.25 I would be happier, but maybe you don't know enough Chemistry to appreciate that yet - and I suspect that is what the last picture is trying to say, but it isn't very clear. The first picture is horrible, well done on rejecting that! Potassium won't ever form a covalent bond to Oxygen, it will always be ionic.

Comment: Formal charges are but a man-made concept.

Comment: In MnO4- all the Mn-O bonds are equivalent and they have the same length. This type of structure is difficult to represent with a single Lewis structure, and formal charges only make sense for a Lewis structure.

Comment: Thank you all for reading my post and answering to my question! @Ian Bush, you're right. I'm still grasping the concept of formal charge. I can't believe I used to draw Lewis structures without knowing about it!

Comment: And @Shoubhik R Maiti, that makes sense. I thought about that after I found two different possible structures online.

Comment: Yes. And you can get an intuitive sense of this by analogy with benzene. The usual benzene structure has three double bonds and three single bonds, but obviously all 6 C-C bonds are same. (which is why sometimes benzene is drawn without the double bonds, but with a circle inside) In spite of the fact that the Lewis structure is not completely right, we still use it. (partly because it helps us draw mechanisms better, and partly because people like to draw octet complete Lewis structures I guess)